# Passing information from form 1 to form 2 is not displaying correctly

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to pass the information from form 1 object to form 2 object. all I am getting is a blank screen on form 2.

here is what I have so far

on form 1 I have :

```
    Private Sub btnTestResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestResults.Click
    Dim obb As New frmElevatedResults
    obb.val = lstHighCholesterol
    obb.Show()
```

On form 2 I have:

```
    Option Strict On

Public Class frmElevatedResults

    Public Property val As Object

    Private Sub frmElevatedResults_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'This Load event displays the results of the elevated cholestoral levels above 200.  
        lstResults = CType(val, ListBox)
```

I have been at this for hours.  Please if anyone can give me an idea of why the list box in form 2 is blank, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here that `lstHighCholesterol` is not `empty` and is also a `ListBox` control. Your `Form 1` code is already correct. Try this:

```
Public Class frmElevatedResults
     Public val as New ListBox

     Private Sub frmElevatedResults_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
           For Each itm in val.Items
               lstResults.Items.Add(itm)
           Next
     End Sub
...
```

Comment: OMG you are wonderful. that worked.  I can not thank you enough

Comment: Seeing that it helped you reciprocates the effort. You are welcome. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :
On form2 add a constructor :

```
 Public Property val As Object
Public Sub New(val As Object)
    InitializeComponent() ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    Me.val=val
End Sub


    Private Sub frmElevatedResults_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'This Load event displays the results of the elevated cholestoral levels above 200.  
        lstResults = CType(val, ListBox)
```

In form1 :

```
 Private Sub btnTestResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestResults.Click
    Dim obb As New frmElevatedResults(lstHighCholesterol)
    obb.Show( )
```